# How to specify an individual register as constraint in ARM GCC inline assembly?

Tags: gcc, arm, inline-assembly

in x86 inline assembly i can write something like this:

```
asm ("cpuid"
            : "=a" (_eax),
              "=b" (_ebx),
              "=c" (_ecx),
              "=d" (_edx)
            : "a" (op));
```

so in the matchin constraints instead of just writing "=r" and let the compiler chose the register, I can say which particular register i want to use (=a for example to use %eax)

how can I do this for ARM assembly?
the ARM GCC assembly cookbook http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html states that i can for example use the constraints
"r" for one of the general purpose registers R0-R15
"w" for one of the VFP floating point registers S0-S31

but how can I constraint an operand for example exactly to s1? or to a particular general purpose register?

Comment: What problem would it solve on ARM to know exactly which register a specific operand is placed in ? What instructions on ARM _implicitly_ modify registers (other than pre/post increment/decrement load/store operations, for which specific constraints exist) ? In this aspect, ARM and x86 are quite different ... what's necessary on x86 is not on ARM.

Comment: @FrankH. System calls? That's actually how I found this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think gcc for ARM allows you to use [constraints](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constraints.html#Constraints) to specify exactly which register to use. However, you can use [explicit register variables](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Reg-Vars.html#Explicit-Reg-Vars) to specify a register to store a variable in:

```
register int my_variable asm("r0");
```

Answer (score 2):

**Explicit register variables minimal runnable example**

Here is an ARMv8 Linux C freestanding hello world exemplifying https://stackoverflow.com/a/3936064/9160762 with some disassembly analysis:

main.c

```
#include <inttypes.h>

void _start(void) {
    uint64_t exit_status;

    /* write */
    {
        char msg[] = "hello syscall v8\n";
        uint64_t syscall_return;
        register uint64_t x0 __asm__ ("x0") = 1; /* stdout */
        register char *x1 __asm__ ("x1") = msg;
        register uint64_t x2 __asm__ ("x2") = sizeof(msg);
        register uint64_t x8 __asm__ ("x8") = 64; /* syscall number */
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "svc 0;"
            : "+r" (x0)
            : "r" (x1), "r" (x2), "r" (x8)
            : "memory"
        );
        syscall_return = x0;
        exit_status = (syscall_return != sizeof(msg));
    }

    /* exit */
    {
        register uint64_t x0 __asm__ ("x0") = exit_status;
        register uint64_t x8 __asm__ ("x8") = 93;
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "svc 0;"
            : "+r" (x0)
            : "r" (x8)
            :
        );
    }
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/122e339b7dee31eac23d93aa0afb1967a5e82830/v8/c/linux/hello.c).

Compile and run:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-user gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -O3 -std=c99 -ggdb3 -march=armv8-a -pedantic -Wall -Wextra \
  -ffreestanding -nostdlib -static -o main.out main.c
qemu-aarch64 main.out
```

Output:

```
hello syscall v8
```

Disassembly:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -S main.out
```

Output:

```
main.out:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400110 <_start>:
void _start(void) {
    uint64_t exit_status;

    /* write */
    {
        char msg[] = "hello syscall v8\n";
  400110:   90000003    adrp    x3, 400000 <_start-0x110>
  400114:   91056063    add x3, x3, #0x158
void _start(void) {
  400118:   d10083ff    sub sp, sp, #0x20
        uint64_t syscall_return;
        register uint64_t x0 __asm__ ("x0") = 1; /* stdout */
  40011c:   d2800020    mov x0, #0x1                    // #1
        register char *x1 __asm__ ("x1") = msg;
  400120:   910023e1    add x1, sp, #0x8
        register uint64_t x2 __asm__ ("x2") = sizeof(msg);
  400124:   d2800242    mov x2, #0x12                   // #18
        char msg[] = "hello syscall v8\n";
  400128:   a9401464    ldp x4, x5, [x3]
        register uint64_t x8 __asm__ ("x8") = 64; /* syscall number */
  40012c:   d2800808    mov x8, #0x40                   // #64
        char msg[] = "hello syscall v8\n";
  400130:   79402063    ldrh    w3, [x3, #16]
  400134:   a90097e4    stp x4, x5, [sp, #8]
  400138:   790033e3    strh    w3, [sp, #24]
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
  40013c:   d4000001    svc #0x0
            : "+r" (x0)
            : "r" (x1), "r" (x2), "r" (x8)
            : "memory"
        );
        syscall_return = x0;
        exit_status = (syscall_return != sizeof(msg));
  400140:   eb02001f    cmp x0, x2
    }

    /* exit */
    {
        register uint64_t x0 __asm__ ("x0") = exit_status;
        register uint64_t x8 __asm__ ("x8") = 93;
  400144:   d2800ba8    mov x8, #0x5d                   // #93
        register uint64_t x0 __asm__ ("x0") = exit_status;
  400148:   9a9f07e0    cset    x0, ne  // ne = any
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
  40014c:   d4000001    svc #0x0
            : "+r" (x0)
            : "r" (x8)
            :
        );
    }
}
  400150:   910083ff    add sp, sp, #0x20
  400154:   d65f03c0    ret
```

**Attempt without explicit register variables**

Mostly for fun, I tried to reach the same result without using register variables, but I was not able to do it.

In any case, the code would be more complicated, so you are better off just using register variables.

Here is my best attempt:

main.c

```
#include <inttypes.h>

void _start(void) {
    uint64_t exit_status;

    /* write */
    {
        char msg[] = "hello syscall v8\n";
        uint64_t syscall_return;
        __asm__ (
            "mov x0, 1;" /* stdout */
            "mov x1, %[msg];"
            "mov x2, %[len];"
            "mov x8, 64;" /* syscall number */
            "svc 0;"
            "mov %[syscall_return], x0;"
            : [syscall_return] "=r" (syscall_return)
            : [msg] "p" (msg),
            [len] "i" (sizeof(msg))
            : "x0", "x1", "x2", "x8", "memory"
        );
        exit_status = (syscall_return != sizeof(msg));
    }

    /* exit */
    __asm__ (
        "mov x0, %[exit_status];"
        "mov x8, 93;" /* syscall number */
        "svc 0;"
        :
        : [exit_status] "r" (exit_status)
        : "x0", "x8"
    );
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/122e339b7dee31eac23d93aa0afb1967a5e82830/v8/c/linux/hello_clobbers.c).

Disassembly:

```
main.out:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400110 <_start>:
void _start(void) {
    uint64_t exit_status;

    /* write */
    {
        char msg[] = "hello syscall v8\n";
  400110:   90000000        adrp    x0, 400000 <_start-0x110>
  400114:   9105a000        add     x0, x0, #0x168
void _start(void) {
  400118:   d10083ff        sub     sp, sp, #0x20
        char msg[] = "hello syscall v8\n";
  40011c:   a9400c02        ldp     x2, x3, [x0]
  400120:   a9008fe2        stp     x2, x3, [sp, #8]
  400124:   79402000        ldrh    w0, [x0, #16]
        uint64_t syscall_return;
        __asm__ (
  400128:   910023e3        add     x3, sp, #0x8
        char msg[] = "hello syscall v8\n";
  40012c:   790033e0        strh    w0, [sp, #24]
        __asm__ (
  400130:   d2800020        mov     x0, #0x1                        // #1
  400134:   aa0303e1        mov     x1, x3
  400138:   d2800242        mov     x2, #0x12                       // #18
  40013c:   d2800808        mov     x8, #0x40                       // #64
  400140:   d4000001        svc     #0x0
  400144:   aa0003e3        mov     x3, x0
            : [syscall_return] "=r" (syscall_return)
            : [msg] "p" (msg),
            [len] "i" (sizeof(msg))
            : "x0", "x1", "x2", "x8", "memory"
        );
        exit_status = (syscall_return != sizeof(msg));
  400148:   f100487f        cmp     x3, #0x12
  40014c:   9a9f07e1        cset    x1, ne  // ne = any
    }

    /* exit */
    __asm__ (
  400150:   aa0103e0        mov     x0, x1
  400154:   d2800ba8        mov     x8, #0x5d                       // #93
  400158:   d4000001        svc     #0x0
        "svc 0;"
        :
        : [exit_status] "r" (exit_status)
        : "x0", "x8"
    );
}
  40015c:   910083ff        add     sp, sp, #0x20
  400160:   d65f03c0        ret
```

This was less efficient for the following reasons:

- `write` constraint `p` need to use an intermediate register `x3` for the `add` to `sp`
- I don't know how to get the syscall return status without an extra `mov` to an output register
- `exit` status gets moved one extra time through `x1`. With register variables is just calculated directly into `x0`.

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10, GCC 8.2.0, QEMU 2.12.

Comment: This is unsafe: nothing tells the compiler that the memory pointed to by  ` "r" (msg)` is also an input to the asm.  With optimization, gcc will optimize away the apparently-dead store to the stack array.  You need a `"memory"` clobber, or a dummy input like `"m"( *(char (*)[]) msg )`  (a dereferenced pointer to an array: i.e. the whole array is the memory operand).  Or since we know the length,  `"m"( *(char (*)[len]) msg )`.

Comment: You don't need to waste instructions on `mov` inside the asm statement.  The accepted answer should work: `register const char * foo asm("x1") = "blah blah"; will make `"r"(foo)` pick `x1`.  IDK why you're giving this big example of the crappy sub-optimal way.

Comment: @PeterCordes ah, I hadn't thought about that that it will be less efficient. I was trying to avoid the register variables as they are ugly, but I don't see a solution in that case. I'll update this.

Comment: This is *exactly* what `register ... asm` locals are for.  In fact this is the only *supported* use-case.  Some other stuff (like using them to read a register without an asm statement) also usually work, but the somewhat-recent change to the docs makes that unsupported.  You could wrap the variable declarations + asm in a `{  }` scope in a larger function, or more usually just the body of an inline wrapper function.

Comment: @PeterCordes let's try again :-)